# How would I create a Python library that is extended by using C?

Tags: python, c, python-extensions

My goal is to create a Python library that I can import into any of my projects, and I wish to have the library made faster by the use of the C language (similar to how NumPy works).

However, after following many different tutorials and videos, I always reach the same error, and am unable to complete the process that the tutorial says I should be able to. I have been following this tutorial from TutorialsPoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions

I have tried googleing the errors though nothing of any value has come of it.

I am running Windows 10 64 bit on my PC, and have both the 32 and 64 bit versions of Python installed (I believed the problem may have had something to do with the incorrect Python version). I have followed the tutorial exactly and have done exactly what it says to do, however, I always result in the same outcome of an error when installing (building?) it.

Here is my C code (named `hello.c`), it is copied and pasted from the tutorial:

```c
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject* helloworld(PyObject* self) {
   return Py_BuildValue("s", "Hello, Python extensions!!");
}

static char helloworld_docs[] =
   "helloworld( ): Any message you want to put here!!\n";

static PyMethodDef helloworld_funcs[] = {
   {"helloworld", (PyCFunction)helloworld,
      METH_NOARGS, helloworld_docs},
      {NULL}
};

void inithelloworld(void) {
   Py_InitModule3("helloworld", helloworld_funcs,
                  "Extension module example!");
}
```

Here is my python setup.py code, this is also copied and pasted from the tutorial, though I have entered the directory to my hello.c file :

```py
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
setup(name='helloworld', version='1.0', ext_modules=[Extension('helloworld', ['C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Python3.7_64bit/Lib/site-packages/PythonLib/CCode/hello.c'])])
```

Once I have done this and saved them all (in the same file) the tutorial says to run the setup.py script with "install" after it. In the tutorial, it says that it should then create the required scipts and data, and that I should be able to import the python package into my code. However, when I run this, I get one of two things, depending on how I run it.

1. I open Command Prompt, run the setup.py with the install after it, just as it shows in the tutorial. This method of running the program will either give me an error code 1120, or it will print out the following:

   ```
   running install
   running build
   running build_ext
   running install_lib
   copying build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\helloworld.cp37-win_amd64.pyd -> C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Python3.7_64bit\Lib\site-packages
   running install_egg_info
   Writing C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Python3.7_64bit\Lib\site-packages\helloworld-1.0-py3.7.egg-info
   ```

   This is what I believe is meant to happen, however, when I try to import the script into my python code, it comes up in the code suggestion window, but says that there is "no module named helloworld" (using PyCharm Community).
2. I open Command Prompt as an Administrator, and do the exact same thing. When I do this, it always gives me the same result:

   ```
   running install
   running build
   running build_ext
   building 'helloworld' extension
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -IC:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Python3.7_64bit\include -IC:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Python3.7_64bit\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /TcC:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Python3.7_64bit/Lib/site-packages/PythonLib/CCode/hello.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Users/penci/OneDrive/Python3.7_64bit/Lib/site-packages/PythonLib/CCode/hello.obj
   hello.c
   C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Python3.7_64bit/Lib/site-packages/PythonLib/CCode/hello.c(17): warning C4013: 'Py_InitModule3' undefined; assuming extern returning int
   C:\Users\penci\OneDrive\Python3.7_64bit\Lib\site-packages\PythonLib\CCode\hello.c : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'C:\Windows\system32\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\Users\penci\OneDrive\Python3.7_64bit\Lib\site-packages\PythonLib\CCode\hello.obj': No such file or directory
   error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 1
   ```

(Sorry for the massive amount of code, I am just not sure what bit will be helpful to solve the problem)

I have tried googling the "exit status 1" though no meaningful results have appeared.

Comment: `exit status 1` gives no useful information. Search instead for `'Py_InitModule3' undefined; assuming extern returning int`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you want to do everything manually, instead of using [Cython](https://cython.org/) ?

Comment: Cython does not work for me either, I have installed it, but when I try to build it, it says it is not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `1`st point I do not have enough information to give you any help. In fact even looking at the error you get intermittently `1120` with `errlook.exe` displays competely unrelated messages.

In your `2`nd point the problem seems to be that the compiler isn't finding the definition of the `Py_InitModule3` function. This leads to the conclusion that you are not linking the correct python library which defines that symbol.

One easy way to achieve correct linking without having to modify the code or the `setup.py` script is to define an environment variable `LIB` that the microsoft windows linker invoked by `cl.exe` will look at to locate the `python37.lib` library.

```
SET LIB=%LIB%;C:/Users/penci/OneDrive/Python3.7_64bit/libs
```

Then you have to run the `setup.py` script in the same console you set the variable in. This will solve the linking problem and if no other issues arises this should allow the usage of your custom module.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, this just leads to getting the error that I stated in the first point. What extra detil could I give to fix that error?

Comment: In the code listing of the 1st point I cannot see any error. So the question is are you getting an error, and if so please post it along with its description, or can't import the extension module?

Comment: The error is not shown there, but sometimes it does create some files, though I cannot import those into python. I use PyCharm, and it comes up in the suggested code box, though says "no module named ... " after typing it.

Comment: I do not know if PyCharm uses virtual environments by default. If you have performed the installation in a different environment then the one PyCharm is operating on for your project you won't be able to import the module. First check you have installed the module in the correct environment.

Comment: I have the file in the correct place, as that is where all of my site packages are. When I run it, it creates "helloworld.cp37-win-amd64.pyd" and "helloworld-1.0-py3.7.egg-info" in my site-packages folder, though I am unable to import them.

Comment: So, supposing your module DLL has been compiled correctly and cannot be imported by the interpreter even if it's in the PYTHONPATH, I would check if all its dependecies have been met with a tool like http://www.dependencywalker.com.

Comment: Does opening `helloworld.cp37-win-amd64.pyd` with `depends.exe` report any issue? Is the interpreter you are using the one built for 64bit architecture?

Comment: How do I use that, I opened the file in it and it gave an error, it said: "Error: At least one file was not a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows module."

Comment: It means that when the loader tries to load your DLL it cannot find the matching architecture for all dependents DLLs. You should check which DLL had the wrong architecture (32bit in your case) and let the loader find the right one before the wrong ones. Usually placing a copy of the correct DLLs in the same folder of the one you are trying to load should suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has fixed the problem. Your help is greatly appreciated.